# Atmospheric Correction of Sentinel 2 L1C images

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2, atmospheric-correction

I'm trying to perform Atmospheric Correction of Sentinel-2 LIC images using the repo of Elias Berra as suggested in the post [Multiple atmospheric correction for Sentinel-2 L1C imagery in Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/414956/multiple-atmospheric-correction-for-sentinel-2-l1c-imagery-in-google-earth-engin)
as follows:

```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2');

// Load the geometries
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ypm-rs-ml/assets/farms_6');
var study_area = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ypm-rs-ml/assets/study_area');
  
// Range to filter the image collection
var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2016, 11, 1);
var endDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2018, 4, 1);

// Function to mask out the cloudy pixels using QA60 band
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60')
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0))
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"])
}

// Filter the image collection by farm
var originalCollection = s2
                        .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate))
                        .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30))
                        .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(geometry))
                        .map(maskS2clouds)

// - Import the SIAC atmospheric correction module
var siac = require('users/marcyinfeng/utils:SIAC');

// - Apply SIAC and retrieve bottom of atmosphere (BOA) reflectance
var originalCollection = originalCollection.map(function(image){ 
    return siac.get_sur(image);
})
```

But, the GEE becomes unresponsive when I try to run the script. Is there a way to run the code to get BOA atmospherically corrected images